# git: Pulling only certain files

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm using the TortoiseGit client on Win XP.  In a particular folder, I have 3 modified files, whose modifications I wish to trash.  In other words, I want to check out the latest versions of these three files from the remote repository.  Note that there is another modified file in the same directory that I wish to leave as is.  How do I get the latest version of only these 3 files?

Thanks - Dave

Answer (score 8):

A checkout with pathnames *does not affect HEAD*:

```
git checkout origin/master -- file1 path/file2 path/file3
```

Assuming default upstream remote/branch names (e.g. after a git clone)

Note that the three named files will be overwritten *without warning*. Any uncommitted local changes to *these named files* will be lost.

Comment: Does this checkout from my local repository or from the remote server?

Comment: @Dave: it gets the files from the reference you name (in this case, the _branch_ `origin/master`, which in most cases is the proper name for your default remote branch (e.g. the one used with `git pull`)). To see what remote branches you have, type `git branch -r`

Answer (score 2):

From the project root invoke the context-menu (Click right-mouse-button assuming you are right-handed ;-).

Select `TortoiseGit > Revert...`

The Revert dialog will show all files you in your repository that you have modified.  You can choose the ones you wish to revert by selecting the check box and then pressing OK.

This brings the selected files back to their original state.

You can then get the latest versions of these files from the shared repository using the Pull... operation from the TortoiseGit context menu (Of course you might wish to commit/stash other changes you have locally).

Comment: What if I don't want to commit/stash the other changes?  I just want to update the 3 files in question from the remote repository and keep everything else as is.

Comment: @Dave You can do that as well from the TortoiseGit menu.  Simply select the files in question and select the **Diff** operation.  TortoiseGit will show the file(s) that are different.  You can drill into each file by double-clicking to see _what_ has changed.  You can then accept or reject the changes.